# I'm having trouble using this function to lower the damage of the enemies in my game

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

So, I made a function to store what happens when a bullet collides with an enemy.

```
public void Hit(Collider other, bool enemyInstanceTag, int enemyLife, int enemyKillPoint)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PistolBullet") && enemyInstanceTag)
    {
        enemyLife -= player.damage;
        player.score += enemyKillPoint;
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

When I try to use it:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Hit(other, gameObject.CompareTag("ERunner"), enemyRunner.life, enemyRunner.killPoint);
    }
```

In every hit the health restore to full health. Imagining the health of the enemy is 2, when I hit it it lowers to 1 but in the next hit starts again in 2.

But if I run this, the health works fine:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PistolBullet") && gameObject.CompareTag("ERunner"))
    {
        enemyRunner.life -= player.damage;
        player.score += enemyRunner.killPoint;
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

The thing is I have multiple enemies and I don't want to repeat the same lines of code, so that's why I want to create a function.

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ints are passed by value, so the enemyLife parameter is a temporary copy.  Change it all you want, but once you're not changing the object's enemyLife, you're changing a copy.

Fix:  Pass in an enemy object.  That is, if you manipulate the object, the changes are permanent.

So, `enemy.life -= player.damage`  should do the trick.

EDIT:

Change the Call from:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Hit(other, gameObject.CompareTag("ERunner"), enemyRunner.life, enemyRunner.killPoint);
    }
```

to

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Hit(other, gameObject.CompareTag("ERunner"), enemyRunner );
    }
```

Then, change the HIT method to

```
public void Hit(Collider other, bool enemyInstanceTag, [Enemy Type or Interface] enemy)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PistolBullet") && enemyInstanceTag)
    {
        enemy.life -= player.damage;
        player.score += enemy.KillPoint;
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

I can't determine the type of the enemy from the code posted, so I put the [Enemy Type or Interface] in there

Further Edit -- How to make this work for all enemy types:

Create an interface

```
public interface iHittable{
    public int DoDamage(int damage)
}
```

Now your enemies will all have

```
public Class TieFighter : iHittable{
// lots of code

// important bit

public int DoDamage(int damage) // from iHittable
{
   this.life -= damage;
   return this.PointsForDamage;  //  could be another method that calculates points, or a field if points are constant.  
}
}
```

Now we can also do:

```
public Class UssEnterprise : iHittable{
{
    public int DoDamage(int damage) // from iHittable
    {
        if (sheildLevel > 0)
        {
            sheildLevel -= damage;
            return 0;
        } 
        else
        {
            life -= damage;
            return PointsForDamage; 
       } 
    }
}
```

So assume our enemyRunner is a TieFighter.  The hit call will still be:

```
    Hit(other, gameObject.CompareTag("ERunner"), enemyRunner );
```

And our method will be:

```
public void Hit(Collider other, bool enemyInstanceTag, iHittable enemy)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PistolBullet") && enemyInstanceTag)
    {

        player.score += enemy.DoDamage(player.damage);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

The trick here is that objects can be many different types, and depending on what type we call them by, we can depend on them to provide different methods.

Comment: I understand but "other" is the bullet that shoots from the player to hit the enemy. The life variable in my EnemyController is an int, that's why I'm passing an int in the function. Can you show me how you would write the function? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that works but I cant use the same function on multiple enemies since I'm calling only the ERunnerController in the method.

public void Hit(Collider other, bool enemyInstanceTag, ERunnerController enemy)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PistolBullet") && enemyInstanceTag)
        {
            enemy.health -= player.damage;
            player.score += enemy.killPoint;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }

I have multiple enemies with multiple controllers and everyone have a different life/health.

Comment: That's all I'm doing today.  If there's any more interest, I'd suggest reading about interfaces and polymorphism, and asking another question.

Comment: That works like a charm! Didn't know about Interfaces, definetly something to check out. Thank you for your help!